# UIScrollview - Blurry effects iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, calayer

I have paging UIScrollview. The UIScrollview is the choice of the user selected. I'm supposed to blur out those pages that is not inside the scrollview frame. Any suggestions on this? Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpCkY.png) for the implemented UIScrollview. The black box with low alpha component is to be replaced by blurry effect on the other pages.

Comment: What have you tried?  Obviously, by tagging this question with the CALayer tag, you have some semblance of an implementation worked out.

Comment: http://www.dimzzy.com/blog/2010/11/blur-effect-for-uiview/ I came across this link. However To add blurry effect on those wheels not inside the frame, I need to add blurry effect on top of the scrollview and out side the frame. This will not allow me to scroll the UIScrollview because it is below the blurred UIView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this with a category on `UIImage` ...

**.h file:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIImage (StackBlur) 
    - (UIImage*) stackBlur:(NSUInteger)radius;
    - (UIImage *) normalize ;

@end
```

**.m file:**

```
#import "UIImage+StackBlur.h"

@implementation  UIImage (StackBlur)    

// Stackblur algorithm
// from
// http://incubator.quasimondo.com/processing/fast_blur_deluxe.php
// by  Mario Klingemann

- (UIImage*) stackBlur:(NSUInteger)inradius
{
    int radius=inradius; // Transform unsigned into signed for further operations

    if (radius<1){
        return self;
    }
    // Suggestion xidew to prevent crash if size is null
    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(self.size, CGSizeZero)) {
        return self;
    }

    //  return [other applyBlendFilter:filterOverlay  other:self context:nil];
    // First get the image into your data buffer
    CGImageRef inImage = self.CGImage;
    int nbPerCompt=CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(inImage);
    if(nbPerCompt!=32){
        UIImage *tmpImage=[self normalize];
        inImage=tmpImage.CGImage;
    }
    CFDataRef m_DataRef = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(inImage));  
    UInt8 * m_PixelBuf=malloc(CFDataGetLength(m_DataRef));
    CFDataGetBytes(m_DataRef,
                   CFRangeMake(0,CFDataGetLength(m_DataRef)) ,
                   m_PixelBuf);

    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(m_PixelBuf,  
                                             CGImageGetWidth(inImage),  
                                             CGImageGetHeight(inImage),  
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(inImage),
                                             CGImageGetBytesPerRow(inImage),  
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(inImage),  
                                             CGImageGetBitmapInfo(inImage) 
                                             ); 


    int w=CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
    int h=CGImageGetHeight(inImage);
    int wm=w-1;
    int hm=h-1;
    int wh=w*h;
    int div=radius+radius+1;

    int *r=malloc(wh*sizeof(int));
    int *g=malloc(wh*sizeof(int));
    int *b=malloc(wh*sizeof(int));
    memset(r,0,wh*sizeof(int));
    memset(g,0,wh*sizeof(int));
    memset(b,0,wh*sizeof(int));
    int rsum,gsum,bsum,x,y,i,p,yp,yi,yw;
    int *vmin = malloc(sizeof(int)*MAX(w,h));
    memset(vmin,0,sizeof(int)*MAX(w,h));
    int divsum=(div+1)>>1;
    divsum*=divsum;
    int *dv=malloc(sizeof(int)*(256*divsum));
    for (i=0;i<256*divsum;i++){
        dv[i]=(i/divsum);
    }

    yw=yi=0;

    int *stack=malloc(sizeof(int)*(div*3));
    int stackpointer;
    int stackstart;
    int *sir;
    int rbs;
    int r1=radius+1;
    int routsum,goutsum,boutsum;
    int rinsum,ginsum,binsum;
    memset(stack,0,sizeof(int)*div*3);

    for (y=0;y<h;y++){
        rinsum=ginsum=binsum=routsum=goutsum=boutsum=rsum=gsum=bsum=0;

        for(int i=-radius;i<=radius;i++){
            sir=&stack[(i+radius)*3];
            /*          p=m_PixelBuf[yi+MIN(wm,MAX(i,0))];
             sir[0]=(p & 0xff0000)>>16;
             sir[1]=(p & 0x00ff00)>>8;
             sir[2]=(p & 0x0000ff);
             */
            int offset=(yi+MIN(wm,MAX(i,0)))*4;
            sir[0]=m_PixelBuf[offset];
            sir[1]=m_PixelBuf[offset+1];
            sir[2]=m_PixelBuf[offset+2];

            rbs=r1-abs(i);
            rsum+=sir[0]*rbs;
            gsum+=sir[1]*rbs;
            bsum+=sir[2]*rbs;
            if (i>0){
                rinsum+=sir[0];
                ginsum+=sir[1];
                binsum+=sir[2];
            } else {
                routsum+=sir[0];
                goutsum+=sir[1];
                boutsum+=sir[2];
            }
        }
        stackpointer=radius;


        for (x=0;x<w;x++){
            r[yi]=dv[rsum];
            g[yi]=dv[gsum];
            b[yi]=dv[bsum];

            rsum-=routsum;
            gsum-=goutsum;
            bsum-=boutsum;

            stackstart=stackpointer-radius+div;
            sir=&stack[(stackstart%div)*3];

            routsum-=sir[0];
            goutsum-=sir[1];
            boutsum-=sir[2];

            if(y==0){
                vmin[x]=MIN(x+radius+1,wm);
            }

            /*          p=m_PixelBuf[yw+vmin[x]];

             sir[0]=(p & 0xff0000)>>16;
             sir[1]=(p & 0x00ff00)>>8;
             sir[2]=(p & 0x0000ff);
             */
            int offset=(yw+vmin[x])*4;
            sir[0]=m_PixelBuf[offset];
            sir[1]=m_PixelBuf[offset+1];
            sir[2]=m_PixelBuf[offset+2];
            rinsum+=sir[0];
            ginsum+=sir[1];
            binsum+=sir[2];

            rsum+=rinsum;
            gsum+=ginsum;
            bsum+=binsum;

            stackpointer=(stackpointer+1)%div;
            sir=&stack[((stackpointer)%div)*3];

            routsum+=sir[0];
            goutsum+=sir[1];
            boutsum+=sir[2];

            rinsum-=sir[0];
            ginsum-=sir[1];
            binsum-=sir[2];

            yi++;
        }
        yw+=w;
    }
    for (x=0;x<w;x++){
        rinsum=ginsum=binsum=routsum=goutsum=boutsum=rsum=gsum=bsum=0;
        yp=-radius*w;
        for(i=-radius;i<=radius;i++){
            yi=MAX(0,yp)+x;

            sir=&stack[(i+radius)*3];

            sir[0]=r[yi];
            sir[1]=g[yi];
            sir[2]=b[yi];

            rbs=r1-abs(i);

            rsum+=r[yi]*rbs;
            gsum+=g[yi]*rbs;
            bsum+=b[yi]*rbs;

            if (i>0){
                rinsum+=sir[0];
                ginsum+=sir[1];
                binsum+=sir[2];
            } else {
                routsum+=sir[0];
                goutsum+=sir[1];
                boutsum+=sir[2];
            }

            if(i<hm){
                yp+=w;
            }
        }
        yi=x;
        stackpointer=radius;
        for (y=0;y<h;y++){
            //          m_PixelBuf[yi]=0xff000000 | (dv[rsum]<<16) | (dv[gsum]<<8) | dv[bsum];
            int offset=yi*4;
            m_PixelBuf[offset]=dv[rsum];
            m_PixelBuf[offset+1]=dv[gsum];
            m_PixelBuf[offset+2]=dv[bsum];
            rsum-=routsum;
            gsum-=goutsum;
            bsum-=boutsum;

            stackstart=stackpointer-radius+div;
            sir=&stack[(stackstart%div)*3];

            routsum-=sir[0];
            goutsum-=sir[1];
            boutsum-=sir[2];

            if(x==0){
                vmin[y]=MIN(y+r1,hm)*w;
            }
            p=x+vmin[y];

            sir[0]=r[p];
            sir[1]=g[p];
            sir[2]=b[p];

            rinsum+=sir[0];
            ginsum+=sir[1];
            binsum+=sir[2];

            rsum+=rinsum;
            gsum+=ginsum;
            bsum+=binsum;

            stackpointer=(stackpointer+1)%div;
            sir=&stack[(stackpointer)*3];

            routsum+=sir[0];
            goutsum+=sir[1];
            boutsum+=sir[2];

            rinsum-=sir[0];
            ginsum-=sir[1];
            binsum-=sir[2];

            yi+=w;
        }
    }
    free(r);
    free(g);
    free(b);
    free(vmin);
    free(dv);
    free(stack);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);  
    CGContextRelease(ctx);  

    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);   
    CFRelease(m_DataRef);
    free(m_PixelBuf);
    return finalImage;
}


- (UIImage *) normalize {

    CGColorSpaceRef genericColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef thumbBitmapCtxt = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,

                                                         self.size.width,
                                                         self.size.height,
                                                         8, (4 * self.size.width),
                                                         genericColorSpace,
                                                         kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(genericColorSpace);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(thumbBitmapCtxt, kCGInterpolationDefault);
    CGRect destRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
    CGContextDrawImage(thumbBitmapCtxt, destRect, self.CGImage);
    CGImageRef tmpThumbImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(thumbBitmapCtxt);
    CGContextRelease(thumbBitmapCtxt);   
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:tmpThumbImage];
    CGImageRelease(tmpThumbImage);

    return result;   
}

@end
```

**using this code to blur an image ...**

```
self.rawImage.image=[self.rawImage.image stackBlur:10.0f];
```

Comment: Its not just about blurring. I need to blur those content not inside the scrollview frame. Is this possible?